Unable to launch Sails DEV mode while using PostgreSQL as database due to long time to load orm hook
Hello fellow developers!  Thanks in advance for reading this question.  I am currently working on a program in which I've been unable to establish a successful launch of sails in DEV mode caused by a long time to load the orm hook attempting to connect to PostgreSQL as the database of choice.
Error: The hook 'orm' is taking too long to load.
Make sure it is triggering its 'initialize()' callback, or else set 'sails.config.orm._hookTimeout a higher value (currently 20000)
at Timeout.toolong as_onTimeout
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
I have searched and found some questions similar, none of which have allowed me to solve the issue at hand such as that located in Sails Orm Hook Timeout/not connecting to postgres database on AWS EC2 and Unable to run my Sails.js application using Postgresql.  To mention a few of the actions I've tried to work around this problem are:

I increased the time in the hook timeout
I cleared the cache to see if this had any impact among different versions of sails (I will comment further detail below)
I have reviewed enormous amounts of links but nothing seems to work.
For this website, I am using Sails@0.12.14, sails-postgresql@0.12.2.  It is worth noting that I have a globally installed version of Sails@1.5.3.  I have node@21.1.0 and npm@10.2.3.  I am using PostgreSQL@12.6
I even reviewed in GitHub the URL https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/7022#issuecomment-669192460 but have not found any bugs or conflicts amongst dependencies that can help me solve (for example, in my case, the versions are different than those listed in the URL and lead me to believe the problem isn't here).

I have exhaustedly reviewed the models (which are 4) and have not found any errors.  I event tried to modify the configuration of the 'models.js' file setting sails to false, however, this did not work as well.  My specific question is, can the hook issue be product of a conflict of the sails versions?  If not, what else should I investigate to solve this issue?
Thanks to all!

Offtopic: PostgreSQL version 12.6 is years behind in maintenance, you are aware of this? Besides that, version 12 will be EOL in the next few weeks. Upgrading to a newer version is advised

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Thank you Frank Heikens, will look into your suggestion once I solve the loading of the orm hook
